# How can I evenly space date data from a data frame?

Tags: python, date, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I have a dataframe of measurements from an experiment.

[image]

I can easily plot the data from the data frame using pandas.  Here is the result.[image]

The dates are evenly spaced on the axis, but in reality, they are not evenly spaced.  How can I get an accurate representation of the time between measurements?

Here is my code for plotting the data frame:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

normal_df= pd.DataFrame(normal, columns = cols, index = rows[2::])
print normal_df

#Write the data frame to an xlsx file

normal_df.to_excel(csv_file[0:-4] + '_Normalized_Survival.xlsx')

avg = normal_df.mean()

errors = normal_df.sem()

avg.plot(marker = 'v',yerr = errors)
plt.title('Mean Survival with Standard Error',fontsize = 20)
plt.xticks(fontsize = 12,rotation = 45)
plt.yticks(fontsize = 12)
plt.xlabel('Time',fontsize = 18)
plt.ylabel('% Survival',fontsize = 18)
plt.xlim([0,6.1])
plt.legend(['Survival'])
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one option you can try, by performing string operations to extract the integer Day and setting the index to be the resultant values

```
In [10]: cpy = [100, 89, 84, 73, 65, 6, 0]

In [11]: days = ['Day 1','Day 2','Day 3','Day 6','Day 9','Day 14','Day 16']

In [12]: df = pd.DataFrame({'day':days,'val':cpy})

In [13]: df['dayint'] = df.day.apply(lambda x : int(x.split(' ')[-1]))

In [14]: df.set_index(df.dayint, inplace=True)

In [15]: df.val.plot()

In [16]: plt.show()
```

[image: Example Plot]